# Error when choosing Print > PDF > Mail PDF - document mail PDF damaged or incomplete?

Tags: mail.app, email, pdf

I'm trying to send a document to email as a PDF. To do this you'd normally go to 'Print > PDF > Email PDF' but when I do this I get an error message:

> The document mail PDF could not be opened because it is damaged or incomplete.

Any idea how I can resolve this? The document itself is a Excel doc, but it happens whenever I try to do 'Print > PDF > Email PDF'. However, if I go to 'Print > PDF > Save PDF' it saves them perfectly.

Any ideas what might be causing my problems?

Comment: Which is your default mail application? Mail.app or Entourage/Outlook (or something else)?

Comment: mail.app, i do have outlook on there but it not setup / the default. Although ive got outlook (not setup/default but on the hd, as with the problem machine) on other machines and they work

Comment: Does sending PDFs from other applications work? For example, if you open google.com in Safari, can you mail it as PDF using `Print>PDF>Email PDF`?

Comment: nope, same problem when trying it with a word doc, jpg and safari

Comment: And can you generate a PDF with `Print>PDF>Save as PDF` from Excel or Safari?

Comment: yeah that works absolutely fine, which is odd ..